# Debian - Run script on startup and display results in console - before user login

Tags: debian, console

How to run script on startup and display results in console - before user login? I've tried to put script in /etc/rc.local but result - of course are not printed to console.

Particularly I want to print machine's IP address and maybe some other info in console after vm startup.

[image]

Comment: problem solved.. I just write an ip address to /etc/issue... thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The content displayed before the prompt is located in /etc/issue.

You can create a systemd script that will fill this file with useful informations at startup (using a systemd service file is the correct way to start something at boot). Combo : the systemd script can be "network-dependent" (After=network.target), and start only when network is ready.

Personnally, I also use /etc/issue.net to write down a warning message for people trying to access the SSH (civil liability for unauthorized access, and so on). Think of it as a sort of "SSH banner".

You can also use /etc/motd to display something when the user has logged in.

Nota Bene : the changes on /etc/issue are visible after a reboot (your script must have run before the last reboot).

Comment: Hi. /etc/issue only displays an information - plain text - you cannot put sctipt into /etc/issue.

Comment: I didn't say that you could put a script in it.

Comment: You didn't either provide soultion to my problem...